# Delete everything except the first word in every paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a long list of Accounts labels which I need to format out the contact information to leave only the name (first word in every paragraph). I have some experience with VBA excel, but this is my first foray into word.

So what I want to do is delete everything after the first word, but leave all paragraph breaks intact, if possible (whoever made the list formatted it with lots of breaks, rather than spacing).

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, modify as needed. Not 100% sure it will preserve your paragraph breaks but this should at least get you to a list of "first word" in each of the paragraphs.

```
Sub FirstWord()
 Dim myString$
 Dim MyDoc As Document
 Dim DocPara As Paragraph
 Dim i%
 Dim p%
 Set MyDoc = ActiveDocument

 For p = MyDoc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
     Set DocPara = MyDoc.Paragraphs(p)
     i = InStr(1, DocPara.Range.Text, " ")
     DocPara.Range.Text = _
        Left(DocPara.Range.Text, i) & Right(DocPara.Range.Text, 1)

 Next

End Sub
```

**UPDATED**

To address leading spaces indenting each paragraph, try this instead. I'm going to modify the above routine so you can see a few changes to this code and how I just adapt it. I haven't tested this version yet, letme know if any problems.

```
Sub FirstWordIndented()
 Dim myString$
 Dim x%               '<-- this is new
 Dim MyDoc As Document
 Dim DocPara As Paragraph
 Dim i%
 Dim p%
 Set MyDoc = ActiveDocument

 For p = MyDoc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
     Set DocPara = MyDoc.Paragraphs(p)

     '// Make sure to ignore leading spaces
     '// This block should remove leading spaces
         myString = DocPara.Range.Text
         Do 
            If Not Left(myString,1) = " " Then Exit Do
           '// Removes the first character if it's a space
            myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
         '// Loop until the first character isn't a space
         Loop 

     '// Some small modifications to use the myString variable in this block:
     i = InStr(1, myString, " ")
     DocPara.Range.Text = _
        Left(myString, i) & Right(myString, 1)

 Next

End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: It's saying invalid procedure call or argument on `DocPara.Range.Text = _
        (Left(DocPara.Range.Text, i - 1)) & Right(DocPara.Range.Text, 1)`

Comment: Try `Left(DocPara.Range.Text, i)`?

Comment: Now it's just crashing VBE and Word. Goes 'not responding' after a few seconds and can't recover.

Comment: Well without the file I can't help, I have added screenshots above to demonstrate that I have tested this and the code works without error for me in Word 2010, Windows 7.

Comment: out of curiousity how big is this file? If it is very large, it might have performance issues, so try breaking it in to smaller files?

Comment: The file is only 327 kb (75 pages), but yes, that was the problem. Now, however, I see that whoever created this used a random number (from 0 to 5) to indent each paragraph. The macro deletes anything indented in such a manner.

Comment: ok... let me think about that for a minute I'll make a (hopefully small) revision.

Comment: Working flawlessly. Thanks for all the help.